# How does the configuration of `AccountStore` in the Balances pallet work?

Tags: account, substrate

In the Balances pallet, the config trait has one item that is defined like `type AccountStore: StoredMap<Self::AccountId, AccountData<Self::Balance>>;`. This was a bit strange to me as I was expecting a normal storage map to store a mapping from `AccountId` to `AccountData` but after I looked at the docs for `StoredMap` I realised that it's a trait implemented on StorageMaps as well. That makes more sense now, so I go on to look at how the runtime defines this field, and to my surprise I find this in the `runtime/src/lib.rs` : `type AccountStore = System;`. Now I've never seen a runtime definition like this before because if I'm correct, `System` is supposed to represent the `frame_system` pallet. So I go to look at `frame_system::Config` for Runtime and I find this defintion :

`type AccountData = pallet_balances::AccountData<Balance>;`.

Now I don't know how these definitions are getting into the `pallet_balances`'s `Config` impl, but I can see that the FRAME `System` pallet contains both types namely : one type `AccountData` and one `AccountId`.

In the end my two questions that stand are:

1. What are the reasons for such a convoluting design?
2. How does `type AccountStore = System;` figure out the concrete types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Storing account balances in the system pallet also maintains some [other frame_system information](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8c3992521c135b8c07e5ec767bbcfabdcc06e090/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L758-L764) that may be important to keep around for a certain runtime configuration. But having `consumers`, `providers` and `sufficients` inside a runtime with multiple pallets and potentially interacting with other runtimes becomes quite crucial.
2. `AccountStore` defines where this balance is going to be stored, for [this case](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8c3992521c135b8c07e5ec767bbcfabdcc06e090/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L434) is `frame_system::Pallet<Runtime>`. If we follow the lead and check the configuration of frame_system we will see that the [type for `AccountData`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8c3992521c135b8c07e5ec767bbcfabdcc06e090/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L218) is defined as

```rust
type AccountData = pallet_balances::AccountData<Balance>
```

Good, now we know that the `AccountData` stored in frame_system will be the one [defined in pallet_balances](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8c3992521c135b8c07e5ec767bbcfabdcc06e090/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L679).

So the information living in system concerning accounts will end up looking like the following:

```rust
/// Information of an account.
#[derive(Clone, Eq, PartialEq, Default, RuntimeDebug, Encode, Decode, TypeInfo)]
pub struct AccountInfo<Index, AccountData> {
    /// The number of transactions this account has sent.
    pub nonce: Index,
    /// The number of other modules that currently depend on this account's existence. The account
    /// cannot be reaped until this is zero.
    pub consumers: RefCount,
    /// The number of other modules that allow this account to exist. The account may not be reaped
    /// until this and `sufficients` are both zero.
    pub providers: RefCount,
    /// The number of modules that allow this account to exist for their own purposes only. The
    /// account may not be reaped until this and `providers` are both zero.
    pub sufficients: RefCount,
    /// The additional data that belongs to this account. Used to store the balance(s) in a lot of
    /// chains.
    pub data: AccountData,
}
```

Where `AccountData` fits the previous mentioned definition in pallet_balances.

Please, check this commit too for further information on how this may be tweaked -> https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/commit/31d90c202d6df9ce3837ee55587b604619a912ba